# We are facing problem with Python Kivy while building APK using Buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, android-camera, buildozer

We are building one Android app with Python Kivy. We are getting the error while building the apk

```
ne 49, in init_camera
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1047, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 768, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 934, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :  
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Full Log

```
    ply_rule
09-27 00:59:23.042 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
09-27 00:59:23.042 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
09-27 00:59:23.043 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
09-27 00:59:23.044 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
09-27 00:59:23.044 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.045 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.045 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.046 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 102, in _on_index
09-27 00:59:23.046 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 42, in __init__
09-27 00:59:23.047 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
09-27 00:59:23.047 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 49, in init_camera
09-27 00:59:23.048 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1047, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.048 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 768, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.049 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 934, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
09-27 00:59:23.049 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
09-27 00:59:23.050 22351 22746 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service
09-27 00:59:23.050 22351 22746 I python  :  
09-27 00:59:23.050 22351 22746 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
09-27 00:59:23.051 22351 22746 I python  :  
09-27 00:59:23.051 22351 22746 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
09-27 00:59:23.051 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 496, in <module>
09-27 00:59:23.051 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
09-27 00:59:23.052 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 491, in build
09-27 00:59:23.052 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 403, in load_string
09-27 00:59:23.053 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 656, in _apply_rule
09-27 00:59:23.053 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 467, in apply_class_lang_rules
09-27 00:59:23.054 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 536, in apply
09-27 00:59:23.055 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 705, in _apply_rule
09-27 00:59:23.055 22351 22746 I python  :  kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 24:
09-27 00:59:23.055 22351 22746 I python  :  ...
09-27 00:59:23.055 22351 22746 I python  :       22:        id: camera
09-27 00:59:23.056 22351 22746 I python  :       23:        index: 0
09-27 00:59:23.056 22351 22746 I python  :  >>   24:        resolution: (200, 200)
09-27 00:59:23.056 22351 22746 I python  :       25:        play: False
09-27 00:59:23.056 22351 22746 I python  :       26:    MDRaisedButton:
09-27 00:59:23.056 22351 22746 I python  :  ...
09-27 00:59:23.057 22351 22746 I python  :  JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service
09-27 00:59:23.057 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
09-27 00:59:23.057 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
09-27 00:59:23.057 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
09-27 00:59:23.057 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
09-27 00:59:23.058 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
09-27 00:59:23.058 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.058 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.058 22351 22746 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
09-27 00:59:23.058 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 102, in _on_index
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 42, in __init__
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "/Users/sourabhdubey/Desktop/FPIndia2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fpindia/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 49, in init_camera
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1047, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.059 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 768, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 934, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  :  
09-27 00:59:23.060 22351 22746 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Do you have the camera permission?

Comment: No, which code we have to add for camera permission?

Comment: Have a look at this [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: we tried. but we are not able to import the android library in mac os. could you please help us to import android.permission.camera

Comment: um , I think we don't need to install or import anything in your `*.py` file.
Just add the `android` to your `buildozer.spec` 's `requirement` 
And add `CAMERA` to the `android.permission` in `buildozer.spec` 

Comment: also , include

`from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

request_permissions([ Permission.CAMERA ])`

in your `main.py` for android camera access  : )